# What will be the path(on server/CPanel) of php file for android application?

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, cpanel

I made a localhost application for fetching and saving information to database in android . The path of php file on localhost(xampp) is

```
private static String url_index = "http://10.0.2.2/prince/select_city.php";
```

What will be the new path `private static String url_index` for android application as i had buied the domain and space on server (suppose www.android.com) and i uploaded the file to public_html to my server(CPanel)

```
private static String url_index = "new path after uploading the file on CPanel";
```

Please help me

Comment: Depends on the domain you buy and the path you put your PHP file.

Comment: This also has nothing to do with Android as the PHP file has no knowledge of what is calling it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you upload the file to the public_html directory, it will be found at the root of your url.  So in your case it would be:

`http://www.android.com/select_city.php`

Comment: Thanks for your support. I will check it. :)

Comment: THANKS IT IS WORKING.